# E: Internal Error, Could not perform immediate configuration (2) on util-linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, aptitude, dpkg

I had an older version of Ubuntu installed. To upgrade I replaced `/etc/sources.list` with one from another machine running `10.04`.

I then ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The upgrade was successful and I am now running `10.04`. I was also able to install packages. However today when installing any packages I am getting the following error:

> E: Internal Error, Could not perform immediate configuration (2) on util-linux

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: @jigar: so when you first copied over the /etc/sources.list the OS was an older version than 10.04? If so, why not just run dist-upgrade?

Comment: @bboy Yes It was older version and I copied sources.list from 10.4, because `update-release` wasn't doing job. upgrade is no longer supported with jaunty some message was there something like this. you want me to run `dist-upgrade` now ?

Comment: @jigar: not sure, I have had problems on dist-upgrade when things get convoluted though. Maybe you could apt-get clean or apt-get autoclean, command is something like that to clear what you have cached, and then update and upgrade again.

Comment: @bboy Thanks. let me try , will be back as soon as it gets done. mean while you can add this as an answer. I will upvote, and accept it(if it works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could apt-get clean or apt-get autoclean, command is something like that to clear what you have cached, and then update and upgrade again

Comment: Thanks. that issue solved but now there is another issue ,*failed to fetch http in.archive.ubuntu.com ubuntu dists lucid release.gpg*

Comment: and resolved that by setting google's DNS. IDK how request from browser was being resolved for the same request..